# Can I detect if trackpad is touched by applescript?

Tags: mac, applescript

For exemple I want to type capital letters when my thumb is on Trackpad, and type lowercase letters when Trackpad is untouched

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  Long answer: it is not possible.